# What does "Prepare to have your pleasure glands carpet-bombed" mean?

Tags: american-english, phrase-meaning

Check it out inside, man. It's bigger than your house. (describing a van )
**Prepare to have your pleasure glands carpet-bombed.**
Watch out for the floors,'cause they're marble.

From the movie [judgement night](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107286/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1993)

Comment: A quick google search about carpet bombing helps clarify... just sayin....

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! Please edit the question to provide more information, in order to enable a quality answer. Do read our [help on asking questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). **Ensure that you include all the research you have done already, and indicate what isn't clear in the information you found.** This ensures that people don't repeat the work you have already done, and can address exactly what you're unsure of.

Comment: I can't wait till we've explained the entire judgement night script! That'll be the day!

Answer (score 4):

This is very much a figurative expression.

There are no *pleasure glands* per se. The author is referring to the various parts of an individual that experiences pleasure.

[Carpet-bombing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpet_bombing), according to *Wikipedia*:

> also known as saturation bombing, is a large aerial bombing done in a progressive manner to inflict damage in every part of a selected area of land.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpet_bombing)[2][3][4] The phrase evokes the image of explosions completely covering an area, in the same way that a carpet covers a floor.

No actual explosive attack is contemplated. Rather, the author is suggesting that

> the experience will cover every aspect of the things that give you pleasure, in a comprehensive and conclusive manner.

It is a bit of hyperbole.

[About a *van*? Really?]

Comment: > About a van? Really?  --> https://www.google.se/search?q=custom+vans

Comment: @Hannu My pleasure glands are somehow resisting.

Comment: Indeed: Personal preferences vary between members of the human race.